# Floating virtual keyboard iOS

Tags: ipad, ios, keyboard

[image: Floating Keyboard]
This happens every now and then. Just this time rebooting my iPad doesn't solve it.

Any idea what caused this? Unfortunately I'm on the go and this makes safari practically unusable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's a feature

Just long click on the bottom right key of the keyboard, when the menu pops up, click **Dock**.

You can enable that by dragging up the keyboard with this key. Also, you can dock him back by dragging it to the bottom of the screen.

[image: image shows button to tap to dock floating keyboard]

---

FYI, you can also **split** the keyboard, making it easier to type while holding the iPad.

Comment: Oh. Nice. Could be helpful.